# Why can't members wear hats on chat?

Tags: support, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016, chat-profile

Why can't I wear hats in chat rooms? I don't see other members wearing it there either -- why is that?

I think that something's wrong with chat, for example in [my profile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/344497/mrly), I am wearing the hat but in actual chat it doesn't show.

Also [this member](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users) doesn't wear it, but in the [room like this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5617097), they do wear  it?

Why does this happen?

Comment: Looks to me like you do have a hat in the chat room: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nHAO.png

Comment: you mean this : http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded ?

Comment: No, I mean in the room. Where you are chatting.

Comment: Sorry @Oded now i can't see the picture because you know politic of companies, i will check it later :)

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, unless you mean mobile chat which has totally different design. Hats do appear in chat, and if not it's because something on your side block them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange is merely following the rules of gentlemanly conduct.

A man should remove his hat upon entering a home, church, or office.

To wear ones hat in a chatroom is very base indeed.

I have considerable faith in the fact that it wasn't simply due to development priorities.

Comment: haha, woww this is a great explanation bravo @Bathsheba :)

Answer (score 5):

I see hats in chats:

[image]

Comment: OP means in profiles, see the links in his question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no, the OP specifically says "**Why can't I wear hats in chat rooms?**", and that's what (s)he means

Comment: All of you, i don't mean that, i mean what i see here : http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/344497/mrly

Answer (score 1):

I guess because it is a whole bunch of work to apply the hat overlay on every place and do it correctly for any size.

The team just focused on the most prominent and visible places to show the hat, which is fine to me.